# How to set exception when selecting random tables from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have an online shop with "Recommended items" list displayed and the way it works is selecting 6 rows from database randomly, something like this.

```
$sql= mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM items WHERE ORDER by RAND() LIMIT 6");
```

You click on an item from a category list and it opens a new window exclusively for that item, where the Recommended Items list is being displayed below it right away.

So my question is, how do I exclude the item that's already clicked and open in a new window, from being displayed in the Recommended Items list (which is displayed below it) again? The php code for the "currently" open window of an item is: `'.$data['id'].'`

A perfect concept of what I'm trying to achieve would be something like this:

```
$sql= mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM items WHERE id NOT '.$data['id'].' ORDER by RAND() LIMIT 6");
```

As hard as I tried to be more clear, this is the best way I could describe my issue. I do hope that wasn't somewhat ambiguous the description!

Comment: How about a mysql tutorial site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use does not equal (!=) in your query.

```
$sql= mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM items WHERE id != '{$data['id']}' ORDER by RAND() LIMIT 6");
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I get the following notice `Undefined variable: data` ..  meanwhilte `'.$data['id'].`' is used on the same page too, so it's defined and I get no errors for it.

Comment: Without seeing any more of your code than just your queries I can't advise on why you might get an undefined error.

Answer (score 0):

Two expressions placed on either sides of the NOT EQUAL TO (`<>`) operator are not equal.

```
<>, !=
```

Your query :-

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE id <> '{$data['id']}' ORDER by RAND() LIMIT 6
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE id != '{$data['id']}' ORDER by RAND() LIMIT 6
```

Comment: Why does it declare data to be undefined? It's already used like the following somewhere on the same page and there's no such a warning for it. `'.$data['id'].'`

Comment: please check value of **$data['id']** is set or not@P4P4DR4G0N

Comment: print the value of $data['id']